# what to fill surface water drainage trench with

Tags: foundation, drainage

[image: surface drainage ditch, steep driveway]

Cabin is at bottom of steep driveway.  Water runs down and into crawl space.  One very large ditch about 15 feet up gets most of it.  This ditch gets remainder.  On hand - 1 inch round stone, tyvek, plastic gutters.

What can i fill this ditch with?  Plastic drains at big box are less desirable due to cost, but I could buy other materials if needed.  Thanks.

Comment: Is the trench across the driveway where it will be driven across?

Comment: Neither trench will be driven on.  Trench across driveway is staying open for now, bridge built across it.  Trench in picture needs some kind of fill so people don't trip in it.

Comment: I usually fill with round river rock for drainage, the reason I asked if it was being driven over is automobiles would pack the rock but human and animal traffic has not been a problem for me.

Comment: How deep should I dig it?

Comment: It depends on the amount of water the trench needs to take away, if 4” deep works without rock I would at-least double it if not triple if you have a good slope double should be enough.